# How read returned value from stored procedure in Spring Jdbc (without out parameters in procedure)

Tags: java, spring, stored-procedures, sap-ase, spring-jdbc

How can I read returned value from stored procedure in Spring Jdbc (without out parameters) ?

I am use Sybase ASE database.

Procedure Example:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.procedureA (
 @a int
)
as
begin
    IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM dbo.T WHERE a = @a)
        return 1
    ELSE
        return -1
end
```

Answer (score 3):

Reference: http://www.databaseskill.com/1270151/
Key point is: SimpleJdbcCall.withReturnValue() directs the SimpleJdbcCall object to put the return value in the result map with key "RETURN_VALUE". So you can access it like
(Integer)simpleJdbcCall.execute().get("RETURN_VALUE")

For Sybase, it is not necessary to declare SqlOutParameter "RETURN_VALUE"

Comment: From my experience with PostgreSQL as database, the return key name is `"returnvalue"`, but [others](http://tothepointtalks.blogspot.ro/2009/12/execute-stored-procedure-in-spring-with.html) have mentioned another possibility, i.e. `"return"` (not sure which database). Could be that the key in the map for the return value of the stored procedure changes depending on which database is being used.

Answer (score 1):

The best approach for handle this is to use [SimpleJdbcCall](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.4.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/simple/SimpleJdbcCall.html) that it's in the Spring-Jdbc project.

With SimpleJdbcCall you can declare in and out parameters for this purpose.

You can do it something like this:

```
SimpleJdbcCall simpleJdbcCall = new SimpleJdbcCall(dataSource);
simpleJdbcCall.withCatalogName("dbo");
simpleJdbcCall.withProcedureName("procedureA ");
simpleJdbcCall.setAccessCallParameterMetaData(false);
simpleJdbcCall.declareParameters(new new SqlOutParameter("a",Types.NUMERIC));
simpleJdbcCall.execute();
```

More info [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.0.M3/reference/html/ch13s05.html)

Hope it helps.

Comment: No, this is procedure. (This is just an example, in fact I have the completed procedure and it is very big, it will not be rewritted.)

Answer (score -2):

This might help, although I haven't tried it myself yet;

http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/data/114859-return-value-of-stored-procs-using-storedprocedure-class-and-not-simplejdbccall

```
public MyStoredProc(JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate) {
    super(jdbcTemplate, "mystoredproc");
    setFunction(true);
    declareParameter(new SqlOutParameter("Result", Types.NUMERIC));
    declareParameter(new SqlInOutParameter("otherparam1", Types.INTEGER));
    declareParameter(new SqlParameter("otherparam2", Types.INTEGER));
    allowsUnusedParameters();
    compile();
}
```